# Thumbnails are bigger in size than the original image

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, media

I don't know why, But I have an image that is 200KB, and after wordpress down-scaled it to lik 70% of the dimensions, the size of the image went to to 400+KB!

What can be the cause of that?

I don't have ANY plugins that mess around with the images and I tried (different host, same db same images) to install some plugin that optimize the images like "WP Smush" and others but they wont optimize the thumbnails at all..

The real problem here is that when I tried to optimize the thumbnail my self (from online websites and from what google recommended) I got to more than 70% save in image size!

So, what can I do to fix that?

Thanks in advance!

By the way, it's happening in almost all my images. If it helps, the format is JPG, the original dimensions is 1281×1152 and the down-scaled ones is 800x630.

EDIT: The original image was saved with "Save for web" in Photoshop, though that information can help too..

EDIT2: I guess it is related to the "Save for web" in Photoshop, because when you resize the photo and save it without "Save for web" the image is increased in size, is there a way to optimize the thumbnails to reduce their size's without affecting the quality? (at least not a lot)

Like the site http://optimizilla.com/, it say's that I can save about 70+% for almost any thumbnail I got (on 90% quality), is there a way to do that for every thumbnail without me needing to creating a whole plugin for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so the problem was that the "Save for web" given by Photoshop wasn't good enough and caused a lot of problems with the thumbnails..

The solution was to take every photo I had in the media and optimize it from http://optimizilla.com/ and re-upload each and every photo.

The thing is, you think that some of those "Optimization" plugins will help you, well, non of them did anything good, just decreased the size by 1-2% max (And I mean EVERY plugin I used).

Hope that helps anyone that got the same problem.

Comment: Have you used TinyPNG plugin?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can simple use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/ewww-image-optimizer/ and then try again. That should work. But solve the problem I need to know if you are using woocommerce plugin or if it is a online store website. If so then you need to adjust the image size first in the woocommerce >> Settings >> Product Tab >> Display and then adjust the image size. After that you need to regenerate the thumbnails using https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Comment: I did use ewww-image-optimizer before, that didn't work. I don't know what woocommerce is, so I guess I am not using it. I tried to optimize the images in ewww and then regenerate the thumbnails before but that didn't work either

Comment: ok. Woocommerce is a eCommerce WordPress plugin to set a store in WordPress.. but now then you need to check if you have any plugin that is resizing or cropping the original image..

Answer (score 0):

I've had some good success with WP Smush from wpmudev, seems like you would benefit from their free version here https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smushit/ their pro version definitely does a good job too, grab a free trial https://premium.wpmudev.org/#pricing and give it a go.

*Not affiliated with wpmudev btw

Comment: Already mentioned in the question that I used "WP Smush". Didn't help

Comment: Didnt see that, but the pro option is still valid, it definitely ran better for us versus the free overall. Also just remembered a similar problem that was fixed by editing the DPI via PhotoShop. Either way seemed you found your fix! Good stuff.